# How do you execute a lua file in sublime text 3?

Tags: lua, sublimetext, sublimetext3

How do you execute a lua file in sublime text 3? I tried opening the console and typing `build <filename>.lua`. I also looked through the menu's for a build and run. Supposedly saving a file or hitting <kbd>F7</kbd> is supposed to execute lua scripts, but that did not work either. I expected 'helo world' to print in the console upon save and all it said was the file was written.

contents of helo.lua:

```
print('helo world');
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can manually [create a build configuration](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/build_systems.html) for Lua. However, I suggest that it is simpler to install a Lua package that includes one.

1. [Install Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation)
2. Open the Command Palette (Ctrl-Shift-P on Windows or COMMAND + SHIFT + P on Mac)
3. Type something like "packins" to get the "Package Control: Install Package" item.
4. After a momentary pause a list of available packages will appear. Type "Lua" to filter to Lua packages.
5. My personal favorite is "Lua Dev". Select this package and Package Control will download and install the package for you.
6. From now on, if your have your syntax set to Lua for a file (Ctrl-Shift-P, "Set Syntax: Lua", or click in the bottom right corner of the window and choose Lua) then **pressing F7** (aka Tools->Build) will evaluate the file using the Lua interpreter.

You may also need to install ["Fix Mac Path"](https://github.com/int3h/SublimeFixMacPath).  At the time of this writing this package was not found by Package Control.  Alternatively, install "Fix Mac Path" by running the following command in terminal:

```
git clone https://github.com/int3h/SublimeFixMacPath.git ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages/FixMacPath
```

Comment: After running this on Mac OSX 10.10.1 I hit F7 and get:  `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lua'`.  The error includes a path.  The path does not include the location of lua: `/usr/local/bin/lua`.  I am trying to figure out how to add this to my path so far without success.

Comment: I'm not on my OS X box at the moment, but does this work? https://github.com/int3h/SublimeFixMacPath

Comment: Thank you!  I'd appreciate your support with a question upvote :)

Answer (score 9):

Go to Tools > Build System > New Build System.

Paste this code

```
{
    "cmd": ["lua", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^lua: (...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.lua"
}
```

Save it as **lua.sublime-build**

To run a lua program press **ctrl+B**.

PS: Ensure that lua executable is in you $PATH

Comment: And this is... the best answer