# Sublime Text 3 Lua compiling error

Tags: lua, sublimetext3

I am receiving the below error when trying to compile Lua in Sublime Text 3.

```
luajit: cannot open : No such file or directory
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['luajit', '']]
[dir: /Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS]
[path: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin]
```

I have tried several packages including the fixMacpaths package trying to fix this. Any ideas?

Edit: Again I have tried most of the solutions on here. This seems to be a file path issue that the mac package is not fixing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you execute a lua file in sublime text 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28237929/how-do-you-execute-a-lua-file-in-sublime-text-3)

Comment: Tried all of that did not fix the path issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [Lua](http://www.lua.org/download.html), in the Terminal:

```
curl -R -O http://www.lua.org/ftp/lua-5.3.1.tar.gz
tar zxf lua-5.3.1.tar.gz
cd lua-5.3.1
make macosx test
sudo make install
```

Create a build system for Lua, in Sublime 3, 
  goto: **Tools > Build System New Build System**
and enter a build configuration like the one [pasted below](https://github.com/rorydriscoll/LuaSublime/blob/master/Lua.sublime-build)

```
{
    "cmd": ["lua", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^(?:(?:\t)|(?:.+: ))(.+):([0-9]+): (.*)$",
    "selector": "source.lua"
}
```

Next, use [FixMacPath](https://github.com/int3h/SublimeFixMacPath) to help Sublime find your programs.

```
git clone https://github.com/int3h/SublimeFixMacPath.git ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages/FixMacPath
```

After installing FixMacPath, the user preferences in Sublime will accept `additional_path_items`.

Next, add addition paths. Open Sublime 3 and go to:
**Sublime Text > Preferences > Settings - User** and edit the file to add the paths so it can find your Lua files, for example:

```
{
    "additional_path_items" : ["~/Documents"]
}
```

Next, create a file to test: `"~/Documents/hello.lua"`

```
print"Hello, World"
```

Finally, exit and reopen Sublime, open the test script and build **⌘b**.

Tested in Mac OS X 10.10.3, Sublime 3 build 3083, Lua 5.3.1.